# Authorize on some controller based from a userlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In an MVC5 application I've to grant the access to some controller only to a strict list of user that can be contained in an XML file or a DB table.
I wished to implement it in the right way, so my Idea was to use the  `[Authorize]` attribute.

I've seen that the Authorize has a property Users that's a `List<string>` but I don't know how to dynamically load from a `DataSource` (XML or DB table).

Is there something out of the box or have I to implement everything from the base?

## UPDATE #1

I forgot to tell that the MVC app has Windows Authentication, so the users are in the domain; but before you ask it's not possible to have the users assigned to a group

Comment: You can inherit from AuthorizeAttribute and override the AuthorizeCore method which will fire each time a user tries navigating to all or some of the actions within a controller, inside this method you can load up this list from the xml or db and check if the user is in it, if not, redirect them or show error page.

Comment: Or you could use the standard practice by assigning those users a particular role/permission.

Comment: @mjwills do they need to login with windows authentication on? its based on domain\user right?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at ADFS?

Comment: excuse doesn't somthing easier can be done? without looking at federations,no the fact of acting on AD is disallowed in this case. I've a list of users if those matches the user that's authenticated, it's ok otherwise error page